# Ignite cache invoke update very very slow when value is Treemap and data in treemap increase upto 10K

Tags: java, ignite, treemap

I have code logic of update ignite cache record,

the cache is defined as:

```
IgniteCache<String, TreeMap<Long, InfoResultRecord>> txInfoCache;
```

The key is cache type string, and for value i use TreeMap for keep the record in order(I need the data to be ordered), but the time used for update is increasing with the TreeMap size increase, what i found is when the TreeMap size around 10K, each invoke for one record add to the cache value treemap is very slow, around 2 seconds, if i have 1K data need add to the Treemap, it will cost 2000 seconds, it is really very slow and not acceptable.

I use invoke to update the cache to add record to the Treemap:

```
txInfoCache.invoke(txType, new TxInfoProcessor(), record);
```

config for the cache is:

```
CacheConfiguration<String, TreeMap<Long, InfoResultRecord>> cacheCfg =
        new CacheConfiguration<>("TxInfoCache");
cacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
//cacheCfg.setStoreKeepBinary(true);
cacheCfg.setAtomicityMode(ATOMIC);
cacheCfg.setBackups(0);
txInfoCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);
```

and the processor for add record to Treemap is:

```
private static class TxInfoProcessor implements EntryProcessor<
        String,
        TreeMap<Long, InfoResultRecord>,
        TreeMap<Long, InfoResultRecord>> {

    @Override
    public TreeMap<Long, InfoResultRecord> process(
            MutableEntry<String,
                    TreeMap<Long, InfoResultRecord>> entry, Object... args) {

        InfoResultRecord record = (InfoResultRecord) args[0];

        final Long oneDayMsSeconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;

        TreeMap<Long, InfoResultRecord>
                InfoResultRecordTreeMap = entry.getValue();

        if (InfoResultRecordTreeMap == null) {
            InfoResultRecordTreeMap = new TreeMap<>();
        }


        InfoResultRecordTreeMap.put(record.getDealTime() + oneDayMsSeconds, record);
        entry.setValue(InfoResultRecordTreeMap);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong? or i use the cache in the wrong way?

I also write a simple test code to veriy the speed when get/put with TreeMap:

```
public class Server2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IgniteException {
        try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("server-start.xml")) {

            IgniteCache<String, TreeMap<Long, String>> testCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("testCache");
            testCache.put("my",new TreeMap<>());

            while (true) {
                StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
                stopWatch.start("1");
                TreeMap<Long, String> map = testCache.get("my");
                stopWatch.stop();
                stopWatch.start("2");
                map.put(System.currentTimeMillis(),String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(1000000000)));
                testCache.put("my",map);
                stopWatch.stop();

                System.out.println("cacheSize:"+map.size()+","+stopWatch.prettyPrint());
            }
        }
    }
}


cacheSize:1000,StopWatch '': running time (millis) = 195
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
00080  041%  1
00115  059%  2

cacheSize:1001,StopWatch '': running time (millis) = 38
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
00028  074%  1
00010  026%  2


cacheSize:3000,StopWatch '': running time (millis) = 139
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
00055  040%  1
00084  060%  2

cacheSize:3001,StopWatch '': running time (millis) = 68
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
00042  062%  1
00026  038%  2
```

It shows clearly when the Treemap size raise, the time consume of ignite cache get/put increase, i think this should be 1~2ms, but here it's xx ms and with size increase it will to xxxms even seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's obvious, that in such case read/write time will grow, since on each operation it will need to copy data from off-heap to heap(and vice-versa) and serialize/deserialize it, however, I've checked your code locally and time grew not so drastically. For example, I got

```
cacheSize:10082,StopWatch '': running time (millis) = 18
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
00009  050%  1
00009  050%  2
```

Anyway, I don't think that you chose a good solution for your use case - I'd recommend storing all this data separately, i.e introduce key with fields for TreeMap string name and certain long key for a row and store these data by rows. Using that, your write operations will be much faster. Also, in this case, you will need to [collocate data](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation) by treemap name. To request all the data you can use SQL with ORDER BY statement. And don't forget to use indexes!

Comment: So, in my case, it is not suitable using EntryProcessor, as this may designed only for small scale handling right? Here i use TreeMap to keep the real data in order, but this need everytime to talk with the whole data. In your suggestion, i should remove the use of TreeMap and using SQL query instead, i have check the document, the ScanQuery have filter and transform, it seems i could use this to get the real need data instead the whole data, please correct me if i am wrong. Also, i have see there is IgniteDataStreamer, i want to know if this is more suitable for my case ? thanks

Comment: in official document, for the IgniteDataStreamer: "built to inject large amounts of continuous streams of data into Ignite cache", is this more suitable for my case and more faster than the previous suggestion?

Comment: You will have unnecessary actions in case of using EntryProcessors for writing collections as for me. As for DataStreamer, yes, it will be faster for the large amounts of data. You can check ScanQuery too, actually, I would recommend checking both approach and comparing results.

Comment: I use EntryProcessors here as it have a internal lock, so i could update the record value in the clousure, if i change the data structure to many key - value pairs, when doing updates, i need change the cache configuraion from ATOMIC to TRANSACTION and using lock to protect the record to be updated, Is there any other way that could do the cache record updates more faster with larget amout of data need be update?

Comment: I don't know your use case, so, I would recommend comparing all approaches that I've suggested earlier to check which one works for you faster. What do you mean as key value pairs here? Normal key-value from cache or key values from your TreeMap?

Comment: As the original cache defination: IgniteCache<String, TreeMap<Long, InfoResultRecord>> txInfoCache;  this use TreeMap save all real data, and use EntryProcesors to update the data in TreeMap it is too slow, so as your suggestion, i want change the cache without the TreeMap, using IgniteCache<Long, InfoResultRecord> txInfoCache; the original key was removed with many caches of the key specified name, so here, the data in TreeMap will become many records(i.e. the key-pairs) instead the old one(only one value, the TreeMap instance)

Comment: well, then, if you need transactions, you need to create Transactional cache, yes

Comment: I am just not clear with your first suggestion, so i add the above words, to make it more clear for me.  this line : " I'd recommend storing all this data separately, i.e introduce key with fields for TreeMap string name and certain long key for a row and store these data by rows. ",  does it mean the explanation in the above comments, i.e. remove the TreeMap, and put all data from TreeMap to ignite key-value record.

Comment: What i realy want is to update the ignite record value quickly and safelly, so original, i use EntryProcessor as it has a internal lock, but it is too slow, so i need another way to do this more faster and safelly(as other thread also touch the record in this cache).

Comment: Most possible that you will need not only String in your key, by also Long field from your TreeMap key, it will be like InfoResultRecordKey with 2 fields

Comment: Got it, Appreciate for you patienece and detail e explantions.